# how vscode extension access environment exported varibales in `~/.zshrc` file

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am implementing a vscode extension and need to access the environment variables through `process.env`, but got `undefined`

how to access the variable in the shell config(like bashrc zshrc)

Comment: Did you start VS Code by running `code` command from the terminal of a specific shell? If not, then how come it reads from the shell config?

Comment: yes, I always use `code` command to start vscode

Answer (score 0):

In your `activate()` function you get an extension context, which has a member `ExtensionContext.environmentVariableCollection`.

Comment: not works,  still can't access the variable export at ~/.zshrc files